# Having problem with javascript toFixed function

Tags: javascript, decimal

I have a question regarding `toFixed()` function. I have some float numbers e.g. 160.325 and 5.325. The returned value of `toFixed()` function  supposed to be 160.33 and 5.33 respectively but it returns 160.32 for 160.325 and 5.33 for 5.325.

I have tried in different ways,

```
Number(160.325).toFixed(2)
"160.32"
Number(160.326).toFixed(2)
"160.33"
Number(5.325).toFixed(2)
"5.33"
Number(160.425).toFixed(2)
"160.43"
```

I expect output to be 160.33 and 5.33.

Comment: What logic are you looking for? Do you want it to always round up?

Comment: This is explained in [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

Comment: `(160.325).toFixed(20)` gives 160.32499999999998863132. It's floating point mathematics that is to blame here.

Comment: A quick fix is to round them up as bigger numbers and avoid toying around with floats:
`rounded = (Math.round(x * 100) / 100).toFixed(2); `

Comment: toFixed() works fine here it will round if necessary. according to your example 160.325 last decimal point is 5 and mathematically no need to round this therefore function doesn't round the number

Comment: You can use celi() function and round up to two decimal points, Math.ceil(160.325 * 100) / 100

Comment: @CertainPerformance yes it should round up for me.

Answer (score -3):

MDN has added a warning for this unexpected behavior. You can read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

> Floating point numbers cannot represent all decimals precisely in binary which can lead to unexpected results

Example:

```
2.35.toFixed(1);        // Returns '2.4'. Note it rounds up
2.55.toFixed(1);        // Returns '2.5'. Note it rounds down
```